# Merging Visual Studio solution files

Tags: visual-studio, merge, solution

Microsoft Visual Studio (2005 and 2008) seems to have fun shuffling the Project IDs (GUIDs) around each time we do a little change in a solution. We found that this little detail leads to frustration each time someone has to merge branches in Source control...

We though about coding a little tool to sort those Project ids before Check In. This way, merging would be easier. 
Is there some option that I missed in Visual Studio Options that would do just that?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372357/merging-vcproj-files-scms-hell#372448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it does not look good so far.

See this question:
[Merging vcproj files - SCM's hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372357/merging-vcproj-files-scms-hell#372448)

closed as this appears to be a duplicate.