# PCL 1.6.0 and Qt 5.5.0

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, point-cloud-library

I have an old project that uses Qt (with a mainform.ui) and PCL that I want to reactivate. On my Win7-machine, I have PCL 1.6.0, 32 bit, MSVC 2010 (from the standalone installer), Qt 5.5.0 (not sure what version exactly, the included QtCreator says: 3.4.2, MSVC 2013, 32 bit) and Qt 4.8.5 (I think 32 bit, MSVC 2010) installed. Interestingly, Qt 4.8.5 does not include qtcreator..

Is it possible to use PCL 1.6.0 with my Qt 5.5.0 installation? Because [here](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/windows.html) it says that Qt 4.8.0 is needed and I am afraid to mix up MSVC 2010 and MSVC 2013. Is my fear justified? And if so, why? Or if not, why not?

If I cant use Qt 5.5.0, can I use my Qtcreator from Qt 5.5.0 with my Qt 4.8.5 installation? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PCL 1.6.0 requires qt4.8.0 it might not work with qt5.5.0 since the include paths have been modified between the two versions and some functions have been removed/moved/renamed.

See : https://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5

If you are using the QTVsAddin and you setup your qt versions properly, you should not have a problem living with both versions (I had both versions on my computer for a while). However, qt 4.8.5 is not directly compiled for VS2013 and qt4 VsAddin is not compatible with VS2013 as far as I know. Though you might not need it :

See : [Using Qt with Visual Studio without add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465932/using-qt-with-visual-studio-without-add-in)