# DVCS (or rather, any non-exclusive checkout VCS) and Windows Forms? Merge problems?

Tags: version-control, merge, windows-forms-designer

Does anyone have any experience with this?

For instance, consider Subversion, Git, or Mercurial, and a typical Windows Forms form.

Whenever someone edits the form, for instance repositions a panel to have a different parent, sometimes the form designer code generator rearranges more code than just that panel.

Does anyone have any experience with how big a merge problem this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I tried to answer [it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372357/merging-vcproj-files-scms-hell/3329377#3329377). Simply put, what we do is to have a "pre-merge" script in [PlastiSCM](http://www.plasticscm.com) (you could use it with your preferred SCM) to "sort" the resx prior to merge. This way we avoid weird issues.

Note: Delphi did a better job handling resources 15 years ago than the newest generation VStudio... :(

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I'm just a one-man team (with git), but I don't think I've ever seen horrible problems. Maybe some manual merges from time to time.

To be honest, where I've *really* had problems is with the .sln files (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372357/merging-vcproj-files-scms-hell) question). A designer.cs file you have a chance of understanding and merging visually. Solution files are a total disaster... I've taken to just taking one side of a merge and then correcting manually afterwards..

How about running a few tests?